# java android getResources().getIdentifier()

Tags: java, android

How do I get the int id value from R. for an id? When I  use `getIdentifier` its just returns `0`.

```
 int i = getArguments().getInt(SELECTION_NUMBER);
 String drawerSelection = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawerSelection_array)[i];

int panelId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(drawerSelection.toLowerCase(),"id",getActivity().getPackageName());
```

**Edit**

Xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/Bus_Schedules"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

log

```
06-10 21:24:30.372: I/System.out(3572): Selection = Bus_Schedules
06-10 21:24:30.372: I/System.out(3572): panelId = 0
```

R.java

```
    public static final class id {
    public static final int Bus_Schedules=0x7f090004;
    public static final int basemenu=0x7f090005;
    public static final int content_frame=0x7f090001;
    public static final int drawer_layout=0x7f090000;
    public static final int left_drawer=0x7f090002;
```

Comment: When it returns 0, it means that the id was not found. What's the value of `drawerSelection`? Have you confirmed that you have an id resource defined with that name?

Comment: You need to post some more information about the problem to get any better response. Use the debugger (or a log statement) to determine exactly what value `drawerSelection` has. Post the applicable xml that defines the corresponding id as a resource. (By the way, you can leave out the default locale argument in the call to `toLowerCase`; that's what it will use anyway and it just clutters up your code.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are converting `drawerSelection` to lower case. As is clear in the R.java file, the case of the identifier is preserved. Try calling:

```
int panelId = this.getResources().getIdentifier(drawerSelection,"id",getActivity().getPackageName());
```

Answer (score 9):

Just checked back in a project I'm writing right now:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("resourcename", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

`getResources` returns `int`.

UPDATE: Check `R.array.drawerSelection_array` to include only ID's of existing elements.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It returns an int for OP as well. The problem for OP is that the int is 0.

Comment: "UPDATE: Check R.array.drawerSelection_array to include only ID's of existing elements."

??????

Comment: Just add drawable name without `R.drawable.`

Answer (score -1):

Try this method.

```
public static int getResId(String fieldName, Context context, Class<?> c) {

    try {
        Field field= c.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        return field.getInt(field);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 0;
    } 
}
```

**Calling**

```
 //edtUserName is my field id
 getResId("edtUserName", context, id.class);
```

Comment: im not using context im using an LayoutInflater and ViewGroup

Comment: and it can not understand what context is in that statement.

Comment: Context is your application base context. Simply get it as-  getApplicationContext();

Comment: You aren't even using context in this method. You should be using getIdentifier()