# TextViews text change in a for loop

Tags: java, android, for-loop, textview

I want to change textViews' texts inside for loop in Android Studio, something like that:

for i=0 ------------> textView0 set text "Default"

for i=1 ------------> textView1 set text "Default"

for i=2 ------------> textView2 set text "Default"

Is it possible to do that? I don't know how to change the textView id inside the loop according to "i" value, can someone help me?

Here's my XML:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="--------------"
    android:id="@+id/textView0"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="13dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="--------------"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:textSize="13dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="--------------"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:textSize="13dp" />
```

Comment: You can set up an array of TextView objects

Comment: yeah, it is fairly possible. You can loop into the child views of the TextView parent. Please show your xml so that we could see if that's the case here.

Comment: checkout my solution @Tymek T.

Comment: Added XML to my question, @SathishKumarJ it's ok but in future i will have many more textViews, so i would like to do this automatically

Comment: try Sohail Zahid answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Performance wise good approach.

```
    int[] textViews = {R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3};
    String[] messages = {"one", "two", "three"};

     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(textViews[i]);
            tv.setText(messages[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a labels collection as well to fetch labels form.

```
List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
labels.add("Default 1");
labels.add("Default 2");
labels.add("Default 3");

int[] textViewIds = new int[3];
textViewIds[0] = R.id.text_view_a;
textViewIds[1] = R.id.text_view_b;
textViewIds[2] = R.id.text_view_c;

for (int i = 0; i < textViewIds.length; i++) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(textViewIds[i]);
    tv.setText(labels.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have all the textviews at the same hierarchy level as you currently have in your xml, you can try this solution:

Wrap the whole thing up in one parent layout, say a RelativeLayout. Then, loop through it:

```
int numberOfTextViews = layout.getChildCount();
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTextViews; i++) {
    ((TextView)(afterSendingMail.getChildAt(i))).setText("Default");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> There is another better approach to read layout, drawable and id **resource ID** in android

```
    String[] messages = {"one", "two", "three"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("textView" + i+1, "id", getPackageName()));
        tv.setText(messages[i]);
    }
```

It will read `id` at run time. May be you have `100 ids` then there is no need to save these **id's** in an array.

**Note**

And use **getActivity()** with `getResources()` and `getPackageName()` inside **Fragment**.
For details have a look at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15488321/3496570) and [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17050988/3496570)