# How do I set image decided at runtime in ImageView?

Tags: android, image

I have an ImageView in which I want to set an image depending upon a random value

What I know is I can set an image like this

```
 public void onRollClick(View view) {
    String[] images={"dice1.png","dice2.png","dice3.png","dice4.png","dice5.png","dice6.png"};
    int diceValue=new Random().nextInt(6);
    ImageView diceImage= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice5);
}
```

where `onClick` method is called on a `Button` click. All images are in `drawable` directory. Currently, I always set image `dice5.png`. How could I instead set, `images[diceValue]`  image?

Note: I am using API 22

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply store the ID of your resources!

```
public void onRollClick(View view) {
    int[] images= {R.drawable.dice1, R.drawable.dice2, R.drawable.dice3, R.drawable.dice4, R.drawable.dice5, R.drawable.dice6};
    int diceValue=new Random().nextInt(6);
    ImageView diceImage= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    diceImage.setImageResource(images[diceValue]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just suggesting to use a image loading library like Picasso right away. This makes the performance a lot better and is super simple to implement. You can get the library here: http://square.github.io/picasso/ and this would be your code to go with:

```
public void onRollClick(View view) {
    int[] images= {R.drawable.dice1, R.drawable.dice2, R.drawable.dice3, R.drawable.dice4, R.drawable.dice5, R.drawable.dice6};
    int diceValue=new Random().nextInt(6);
    ImageView diceImage= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Picasso.with(this).load(images[diceValue]).into(diceImage);
}
```

Edit: You should definitely bump up your API version ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getResources().getIdentifier()` for get and id from a resources name.
More info here [java android getResources().getIdentifier()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862000/java-android-getresources-getidentifier) and here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: In this case, get resources by name is not a suitable solution, @pdegand59 's answer is easier.

Comment: @sagix Why it's not suitable? The solution can be `diceImage.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(getimages[diceValue],"drawable",getPackageName());`

Comment: It is more complicated solution than a list of resource ids.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onRollClick(View view) {
    int[] images={R.drawable.dice1,R.drawable.dice2,R.drawable.dice3,R.drawable.dice4,R.drawable.dice5,R.drawable.dice6};
    int diceValue=new Random().nextInt(6);
    ImageView diceImage= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    diceImage.setImageResource(images[diceValue]);
}
```

Instead of string array create array of int drawables. so you can directly  use them.

I have edited your function.