# Resource string is set to "0" when retrieving via getResources and getIdentifier

Tags: java, android, android-resources, android-button

I´m programming with Java in Android Studio.

I just don´t get it, why this happens:

The result of my `setText()` method is always the same: "0" is shown as buttontext.

The `setText` method of my button:

```
button_adj1.setText(String.valueOf(getResources().getIdentifier("adj"+ counter,"String", getPackageName())));
```

The counter variable works correctly and gets incremented after click, which should extract the `counter+1` item at second click.

If I replace `counter` with e.g. `3`, the result is also `0`.

Hardcoded attempt:

```
button_adj1.setText(String.valueOf(getResources().getIdentifier("adj"+ 3,"String", getPackageName())));
```

The resource file: `res/strings.xml`:

```
<string name="adj1">Test0</string>
<string name="adj2"Test1</string>
<string name="adj3">Test2</string>
<string name="adj4">Test3</string>
<string name="adj5">Test4</string>
<string name="adj6">Test5</string>
<string name="adj7">Test6</string>
<string name="adj8">Test7</string>
<string name="adj9">Test8</string>
<string name="adj10">Test</string>
```

Is there any other possible way?

I thought `String.valueOf` is converting the result of `getResources.getIdentifier` into string?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java android getResources().getIdentifier()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862000/java-android-getresources-getidentifier)

Comment: Thank you for your advice.

Solution below worked for this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing it from:

```
button_adj1.setText(String.valueOf(getResources().getIdentifier("adj"+ counter,"String", getPackageName())));
```

To:

```
button_adj1.setText(getResources().getIdentifier("adj"+ counter,"string", getPackageName()));
```

The changes:

1. Use "string" not "String" in the call to `getIdentifier()` -> This solves the issue with the `TextView` being set to `0`
2. Remove `valueOf` and instead pass the resource ID of the string to `setText()` -> This prevents the `TextView` being set to `2131755036` for example

`setText()` has a couple of different overloads. But you want to ensure that this one is invoked:

```
public final void setText (int resid)
```

Not this one:

```
public final void setText (CharSequence text)
```

If on the other hand you want to use the latter overload, then `getString()` must be called passing the integer value of the resource ID.

[TextView Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(int))